# How to setup jmh testing for orientdb embedded?

Tags: java, benchmarking, orientdb, jmh, nosql

I am trying to setup a jmh test for orient db embedded. The test suite is as follows:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class OrientDbTest {
    private OObjectDatabaseTx db;
    private Person[] personList;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        deleteDir("/tmp/orientdb/");
        db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("plocal:/tmp/orientdb/person").create();
        ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
        loadData();
    }

    @TearDown
    public void cleanUp() {
        if (db != null) {
            ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
            db.commit();
            db.drop();
            db.close();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public void benchmarkInsertCompany() {
        ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Person.class);

        for (Person person : personList) {
            db.save(person);
        }
    }

    void loadData() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        personList = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Person[].class);
    }

    void deleteDir(String dirName) {
        File file = new File(dirName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File child : files) {
                    if (child.isDirectory()) {
                        deleteDir(child.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        child.delete();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This project is a gradle project and I am running using gradle-jmh plugin. Here is the jmh settings in build.gradle file:

```
jmh {
    jmhVersion = '1.14'
    iterations = 10 // Number of measurement iterations to do.
    fork = 2 // How many times to forks a single benchmark. Use 0 to disable forking altogether
    jvmArgs = '-server -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=15986m'
    resultsFile = project.file("${project.buildDir}/reports/jmh/results.txt") // results file
    profilers = ['cl', 'gc', 'hs_thr'] // Use profilers to collect additional data. Supported profilers: [cl, comp, gc, stack, perf, perfnorm, perfasm, xperf, xperfasm, hs_cl, hs_comp, hs_gc, hs_rt, hs_thr]
    resultFormat = 'CSV' // Result format type (one of CSV, JSON, NONE, SCSV, TEXT)
    threads = 4 // Number of worker threads to run with.
    timeUnit = 'ms' // Output time unit. Available time units are: [m, s, ms, us, ns].
    warmupForks = 2 // How many warmup forks to make for a single benchmark. 0 to disable warmup forks.
    warmupIterations = 10 // Number of warmup iterations to do.
}
```

When I am running the test, I am getting below error:

```
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=10,384MB (heap=3,554MB direct=15,986MB os=15,986MB)
<failure>

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageExistsException: Cannot create new storage 'plocal:/tmp/orientdb/person' because it is not closed
        DB name="person"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.create(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:423)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.create(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:125)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:429)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:389)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.create(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:75)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.OrientDbTest.setUp(OrientDbTest.java:24)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest._jmh_tryInit_f_orientdbtest0_G(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:400)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.benchmarkInsertCompany_AverageTime(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:149)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:430)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong in the setup here?

**EDIT**:

After reading [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html), I modified the code as follows:

```
public class OrientDbTest {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class TestState {
        private OObjectDatabaseTx db;
        private Person[] personList;
        private BenchmarkTestHelper testHelper = new BenchmarkTestHelper();

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void setUp() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("started setup code");
            testHelper.deleteDir("/tmp/orientdb/");

            try {
                db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("plocal:/tmp/orientdb/person").open(null, null);
                db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Person.class);
                personList = testHelper.loadData();
            } finally {
                if (db != null) {
                    db.close();
                }
            }
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Trial)
        public void cleanUp() {
            System.out.println("started cleanup code");
            if (db != null) {
                ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
                db.commit();
                db.drop();
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public void benchmarkInsertCompany(TestState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        OObjectDatabaseTx db = state.db;
        Person[] personList = state.personList;

        ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
        for (Person person : personList) {
            blackhole.consume(db.save(person));
        }
    }
}


class BenchmarkTestHelper {
    Person[] loadData() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Person[].class);
    }

    void deleteDir(String dirName) {
        File file = new File(dirName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File child : files) {
                    if (child.isDirectory()) {
                        deleteDir(child.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        child.delete();
                    }
                }
                file.delete();
            } else {                   
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the new setup, I am getting below error:

```
# JMH 1.14 (released 19 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_77, VM 25.77-b03
# VM invoker: /home/anindya/app/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java
# VM options: -server -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=15986m
# Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.OrientDbTest.benchmarkInsertCompany

# Run progress: 50.00% complete, ETA 00:01:28
# Warmup Fork: 1 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: started setup code
Sep 26, 2016 11:15:57 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=10,384MB (heap=3,554MB direct=15,986MB os=15,986MB)
started setup code
started setup code
started setup code
<failure>

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageExistsException: Cannot create new storage 'plocal:/tmp/orientdb/person' because it is not closed
        DB name="person"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.create(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:423)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.create(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:125)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:429)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:389)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.create(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:75)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.OrientDbTest$TestState.setUp(OrientDbTest.java:28)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest._jmh_tryInit_f_teststate1_G(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:409)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.benchmarkInsertCompany_AverageTime(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:153)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:430)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

...

# Run progress: 87.50% complete, ETA 00:00:18
# Fork: 2 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: started setup code
Sep 26, 2016 11:16:38 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=10,384MB (heap=3,554MB direct=15,986MB os=15,986MB)
started setup code
started setup code
started setup code
<failure>

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.OrientDbTest$TestState.setUp(OrientDbTest.java:28)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest._jmh_tryInit_f_teststate1_G(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:409)
        at org.dizitart.no2.benchmark.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.benchmarkInsertCompany_AverageTime(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsertCompany_jmhTest.java:153)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:430)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Sep 26, 2016 11:16:49 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Orient Engine is shutting down...
Sep 26, 2016 11:16:49 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: - shutdown storage: person...
```

Comment: This does not look like JMH fault. See if create/cleanup procedures work correctly: e.g. yank them into the `main`, and try to run create-cleanup-create-cleanup continuously. I don't think `deleteDir` you have actually removes all the folders (e.g. after deleting the folder contents).

Comment: Do you have some other process using the same orient instance?

Comment: No. Not from outside the test instance. But what I suspect is somehow other jmh thread is holding the db while another thread is trying to create it.

Comment: What version are you using? Where do you call your `cleanUp` method? You may find some helpful information on transcations here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transactions.html

Comment: I am using 2.2.10. And for this testing I don't need transaction as such. My main idea is to - create db -> insert data into iterations -> collect benchmark stat -> clean up, delete db and repeat. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: At what point are you doing cleanup?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. JMH is meant to do the cleanup when it executes cleanUp method marked with the @TearDown annotation after each trial run. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm asking this because `db.drop();` probably isn't executed, so you are getting error: `Cannot create new storage because it is not closed`

Comment: You are right. db.drop() is not being called at proper time by JMH. That's why setUp code throwing exception. So there is issue in setting up JMH here. But I am not sure how to configure it otherwise so that cleanUp code would call at proper time.

Comment: I don't get it. The log seems to indicate setup() method was entered by all four threads. While JMH should maintain that for `@State(Benchmark)` only one thread enters the `setup()`. Please provide MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev please find the MCVE - https://github.com/anidotnet/orientdb-benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are couple of troubles:

a) The `setUp()` method itself is buggy, it throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx
    at jmh.demo.OrientDbTest$TestState.setUp(OrientDbTest.java:30)
    at jmh.demo.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsert_jmhTest._jmh_tryInit_f_teststate1_G(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsert_jmhTest.java:409)
    at jmh.demo.generated.OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsert_jmhTest.benchmarkInsert_AverageTime(OrientDbTest_benchmarkInsert_jmhTest.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
```

b) `@Setup` method for `@State(Benchmark)` is supposed to be executed only once. But, due to the [bug in JMH](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/CODETOOLS-7901809), if first thread failed with the exception above, then other threads would *also* try to enter `@Setup` and then they will try to open the database, but fail, because it is already open?

In fact, the failure (a) is visible even in the original post, and what exception would get reported from multiple threads entering `@Setup` would depend on sheer luck (this got better in JMH 1.14.1). It reliably fails with that proper exception if you set threads=1. Also, the cleanup path in `setUp()` does not look consistent with `tearDown()`, which may explain why re-entered threads fail to open the DB.

Bottom-line: before doing multi-threaded tests, try doing the single-threaded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Using fork was the culprit. I have post the working code in the answer

Comment: Wait, no! If your test works with `fork(0)`, but does not with `fork(1)`, then your test is broken. You are not supposed to share data between different trials. Also, half of JMH is not working properly with zero forks, for which it will print a scary message.

Comment: I tried with fork(1), but after that orientdb goes into some kind of deadlock with this code. In log I only get like - 

(interrupt*)(interrupt*)...

Comment: Are there any real life scenarios where jmh is used on shared resources like database? Even orientdb has jmh tests on internal data structures but not on database itself.

Answer (score 0):

`db.drop();` isn't executed, so you are getting error: `Cannot create new storage because it is not closed`

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey's answer helped me to figure out that using **fork** in the test was wrong. I am posting the working code here to avoid more cluttering in the question.

```
public class OrientDbTest {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class TestState {
        private OObjectDatabaseTx db;
        private Person[] personList;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void setUp() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("started setup code");
            try {
                personList = loadData();
                deleteDir("/tmp/orientdb/");
                db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("plocal:/tmp/orientdb/person");
                if (db.exists()) {
                    db.open("admin", "admin");
                    db.drop();
                }
                db.create();
                db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Person.class);
                db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Address.class);
                db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(PrivateData.class);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("error in creating db ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Trial)
        public void cleanUp() {
            System.out.println("started cleanup code");
            if (db != null) {
                ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
                db.commit();
                db.close();
            }
        }

        private void deleteDir(String dirName) {
            File file = new File(dirName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                File[] files = file.listFiles();
                if (files != null) {
                    for (File child : files) {
                        if (child.isDirectory()) {
                            deleteDir(child.getAbsolutePath());
                        } else {
                            child.delete();
                        }
                    }
                    file.delete();
                } else {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }

        private Person[] loadData() throws IOException {
            InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Person[].class);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    @Fork(0)
    public void benchmarkInsert(TestState state, Blackhole blackhole) {
        OObjectDatabaseTx db = state.db;
        Person[] personList = state.personList;

        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("db null.. exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db.getUnderlying());
        for (Person person : personList) {
            blackhole.consume(db.save(person));
        }
    }
```